# prevent deep copy on python

Tags: python, design-patterns, deep-copy

The problem is the following : suppose you have a class 'P' (defined on python), containing some parameters, you want to pass through your main code to differents objects on your code.

It there any way, to prevent that your instance p of class P, created on the main class, is 'deep copied' throught the code ? ( and ideally, that no other module can instantiate an element of class P, for exemple by forcing at most on instance of the class, is there a short way to do that on python?).

The aim is to change dynamically, the parameters of of instance P, on the main code (only), and transfer the modification to the whole code with no additionnal manual setting.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I reply to my own question , I think that it should do the trick (but if there is a more pythonic and simple way.. I'd love to know):
the module p containing the class P

```
class P(object):
    instance = None
    nb_instance = 0
    def __init__(self, **params):
        assert type(self).instance is None, "no more than one instance of P is possible"
        self.params = params
        type(self).instance = self
        type(self).nb_instance +=1

    def __deepcopy__(self,el):
        assert 1==0, "no deep copy of P is possible"

    def __copy__(self):
        assert 1==0, "no shallow copy of P is possible"
```

an other module that trys to instantiate a new element from class P

```
import p


class OtherCode(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.p = p.P(sigma=4.0,mu=1.0)
```

and finally the main code to run

```
import p,otherCode
import copy
if __name__ == '__main__':
    P1 = p.P(sigma=0.1,mu=1.0)
    #o =otherCode.OtherCode()
    try:
        P2 = copy.deepcopy(P1)
    except Exception as E:
        print(E)
    try:
        P3 = copy.copy(P1)
    except Exception as E:
        print(E)
    try:
        otherCode.OtherCode()
    except Exception as E:
        print(E)
    P5 = P1

    print("P1 is P5 {}".format(P1 is P5))
```

```
The output:
no deep copy of P is possible
no shallow copy of P is possible
no more than one instance of P is possible
P1 is P5 True
```